# phpMyadmin DELIMITER Error True or False?

Tags: mysql, delimiter

I'm kinda confused after reading a lot online about using delimiters for stored procedures and triggers etc.

From my understanding a trigger block should be written as such in regard to the delimiter:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS innovationevents.Task9Trigger1;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER innovationevents.Task9Trigger1 
BEFORE INSERT ON innovationevents.tblattendees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO innovationevents.tblregistration 
(RegistrationID, AttendeeID, EventID, RegistrationDate, RegistrationPaid) 
VALUES (40, new.AttendeeID, 3, CURDATE(), 0);

END //
```

Now the thing with this is I get an error message in phpMyadmin, yet the code still runs. I'm thinking maybe it's wrong? or is there any more complex explanation to this as to why my code is wrong? really bugs me seeing this error all the time :P

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`DELIMITER`** directive belongs not to the MySQL database but to the `mysql` command-line client.

Normally, `mysql` recognizes the semicolon (`;`) as the end-of-input marker which causes it to transmit the current contents of the command buffer to the database for execution. Use of the **`DELIMITER`** directive allows you to enter a compound command (eg. as the body of a `CREATE PROCEDURE`) with the component simple commands terminated by semicolons without triggering a premature end-of-input.

MySQL Workbench also requires use of the **`DELIMITER`** directive, but other clients do not, including (as I recall) phpMyAdmin. It would be easy for you to verify this experimentally.

Comment: Nice thanks for the explenation that makes more sense now as to why its needed. However i don't see why workbench requires it. I will test this out :)