# Error in create function syntax developed with MySql not working in MariaDB on PhpMyAdmin SQL console

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following ***create function*** block for SQL

```
/**
 * tos_get_duration.sql
 *
 * Given time unit in seconds, it converts to more readable format
 *
 * Eg. SELECT TOS_GET_DURATION(72) => 00d 0:1:12
 */

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TOS_GET_DURATION;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION TOS_GET_DURATION(seconds INT) 
  RETURNS VARCHAR(16) 
BEGIN
  RETURN CONCAT(LPAD(FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds)) / 24), 2, 0), ' days ',TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds % (24 * 3600)), '%H:%i:%s'));
END; 
$$
DELIMITER;
```

it is taken from [timeonsite analytics reporting](https://github.com/saleemkce/timeonsite_analytics/blob/master/tos_get_duration.sql) query page.

It used to be working well in MySql but I recently switched to MariaDB and tried executed this function; this function basically converts seconds to more human readable string format. I get following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Server version: 10.5.16-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
```

Kindly help me find the issue and **suggest me common "create function" format I can use in both** MySql and MariaDB databases.

Comment: DELIMITER is not SQL statement but client command. Read PhpMyAdmin documentation about how the stored objects should be created correctly.

Comment: PS. In your particular case you may simply remove BEGIN-END and both DELIMITER lines.

Comment: 'suggest me common "create function" format I can use in both MySql and MariaDB databases.' - can't do that  mysql and mariadb are diverging and have diverged to the point where mariadb can't be considered a drop in replacement for mysql. (in my opinion)

Comment: Need a space after `DELIMITER` and the `DETERMINISTIC` keyword. See [Delimitres](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/) and [CREATE FUNCTION](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-function/) - [MySQL 8 fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qsDtYVw7GrkJW5suNsrfd1/0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpMyadmin DELIMITER Error True or False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243762/phpmyadmin-delimiter-error-true-or-false)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your valuable comments. I've upvoted each one of the comments because they are quite valuable. Based on your suggestions, I've created a common fiddle for both and share it here. The point is, we can remove ***BEGIN/END*** statements and remove ***DELIMITER*** keywords as well.

The common code works in both MySQL and MariaDB except that MySQL latest versions expect ***DETERMINISTIC*** keyword to work.

**MariaDB** https://dbfiddle.uk/PK8F8ng4

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TOS_GET_DURATION;
CREATE FUNCTION TOS_GET_DURATION(seconds INT) 
  RETURNS VARCHAR(16)
  RETURN CONCAT(LPAD(FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds)) / 24), 2, 0), ' days ',TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds % (24 * 3600)), '%H:%i:%s'));

SELECT TOS_GET_DURATION(860000);
```

**MySQL** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qsDtYVw7GrkJW5suNsrfd1/9

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TOS_GET_DURATION;
CREATE FUNCTION TOS_GET_DURATION(seconds INT) 
  RETURNS VARCHAR(16) DETERMINISTIC
  RETURN CONCAT(LPAD(FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds)) / 24), 2, 0), ' days ',TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds % (24 * 3600)), '%H:%i:%s'));

SELECT TOS_GET_DURATION(860000);
```

The output:

```
09 days 22:53:20
```

I also agree to Salmon's point,

> can't do that mysql and mariadb are diverging and have diverged to the
> point where mariadb can't be considered a drop in replacement for
> mysql.

But the point is, we have numerous applications that were built as part of LAMP stack. So, we need common code formats like this to make easy switch for the time being. We'll keep it open for additional suggestions from others. This issue is first identified when I worked on [timeonsite.js](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite) when trying to run query complex sub-queries to analyze user engagement in web applications.

Finding top 10 sessions for user engagement in application:

Line 2 uses user-defined function ***TOS_GET_DURATION*** in MariaDB

```
SELECT 
  TOS_GET_DURATION(max_timeonsite) as 'Session Duration', 
  tos_session_key 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      MAX(timeonsite) AS max_timeonsite, 
      tos_session_key 
    FROM 
      tos 
    GROUP BY 
      tos_session_key 
    ORDER BY 
      max_timeonsite DESC 
    LIMIT 
      10
  ) timeonsite_large_sessions;
```

Query Output

[image: Top 10 user sessions for measuring user engagement - timeonsite.js]